# why don't display received sms in program?

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, broadcastreceiver

i wrote send and receive sms in eclips. i set special phone number.when sms received from special number ,sms go in program and for other sms , go to inbox of phone.now, when sms received from special number, program is opened but don't show in program.
please help me.

receive.java

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public String str = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null) {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) 
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                //for get sms from special number===============================
                String msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                Log.v("msg_from >>",msg_from);     
                if(msg_from.equals("09124502715"))
                {
                    //===============================
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";
                }

            }
            // ---display the new SMS message---
            // Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent act = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            act.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            act.putExtra("message", str);
            context.startActivity(act);
        }

        abortBroadcast();
        }
    }



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 private TextView showSms;

    private String   ReceivedSms;

  @Override

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   // _smsReceiver.onReceive(getBaseContext(), getIntent());

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Intent _intent = getIntent();

   ReceivedSms = _intent.getStringExtra("message");

    showSms = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txt_Show);

    showSms.setText(ReceivedSms);

}


 @Override

  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{

 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

      return true;

 }

}



public class SMS extends Activity {

     Button btnSendSMS;
        EditText txtPhoneNo;
        EditText txtMessage;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

            btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
            txtPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNo);
            txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

            btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {                
                    String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                    String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();                 
                    if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)                
                        sendSMS(phoneNo, message);                
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });        
        } 
        private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(SENT), 0);

            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            //---when the SMS has been sent---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the activity you are using to manfest.xml? Not doing so could cause a null pointer exception, in any case past some of the log cat errors...

Answer (score 0):

SmsMessage.getOriginatingAddress
-Returns the originating address (sender) of this SMS message in String form or null if unavailable.If you are using sendsms() method .it will pass the sender adress as null.
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);

also you shoul commend the line abortBroadcast() method.Because this leading to something unbehaviour.